# Estou com uma duvida no text_input do kivy + sql

Tags: sql, python, python-kivy

Olá, estou tentando fazer uma pagina de cadastro e estou fazendo alguns testes neste código, por exemplo, estou tentando fazer com que quando eu insiro um nome no campo usuário e aperto entrar salve este dado no SQL, mas está dando erro, alguém poderia me dar uma luz?

Python:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, Table
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import String

DATABASE = 'sqlite:///divinodb.db'
metadata = MetaData()
engine = create_engine(DATABASE)
cadastro = Table('cadastro', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)

class PaginaInicial(Screen):
    def gravar(self):
        nome = self.root.ids.usuario.textinput
        if nome == type(String):
            nome.execute('INSERT nome FROM cadastro')
            results = cadastro.execute(nome).fetchall()
            print(results)
            return results

class PageEsqsenha(Screen):
    pass

class PageCadastro(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    def switch_to_pageCadastro(self):
        self.current = 'pageCadastro'
    def switch_to_paginaInicial(self):
        self.current = 'paginaInicial'
    def switch_to_pageEsqsenha(self):
        self.current = 'pageEsqsenha'
# Database connection

class TesteDbApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = ScreenManagement()
        return self.root
if __name__ == '__main__':
    TesteDbApp().run()
```

kivy:

```
<ScreenManagement>:
    PaginaInicial:
    PageCadastro:
    PageEsqsenha:

<PaginaInicial>:
    name:'paginaInicial'
    FloatLayout:

        Image:
            source:"images/super.png"
            size_hint:(1, .3)
            pos_hint:{"center_x":.5, "center_y":.65}

        Image:
            source:"images/Logo.jpg"
            size_hint:(.8, .6)
            pos_hint:{"center_x":.5,"center_y":.9}

        Label:
            text:"Usuario: "
            size_hint:(None,None)
            pos_hint:{"center_x":.37, "center_y":.43}
            bold:True
            font_size:"15sp"

        Label:
            text:"Senha: "
            size_hint:(None,None)
            pos_hint:{"center_x":.37,"center_y":.36}
            bold:True
            font_size:"15sp"

        TextInput:
            id: usuario
            pos_hint:{"center_x":.59, "center_y":.43}
            size_hint:(.25,.05)
            multiline:False
            write_tab: False
        TextInput:
            id: senha
            pos_hint:{"center_x":.59, "center_y":.36}
            size_hint:(.25,.05)
            multiline:False
            write_tab:False
            password:True

        Button:
            text:"Entrar"
            pos_hint:{"center_x":.5,"center_y":.28}
            size_hint:(.3,.05)
            background_down:''
            background_color:[16,16,16,0.1]
            on_press:root.gravar()

        Button:
            text:"Esqueceu sua senha?"
            size_hint:(.25,.03)
            pos_hint:{"center_x":.5,"center_y":.2}
            bold:True
            font_size:"8sp"
            on_release:app.root.switch_to_pageEsqsenha()
            background_color:[1,1,1,0]
        Button:
            text:"Cadastre-se!"
            size_hint:(.15,.03)
            pos_hint:{"center_x":.5,"center_y":.15}
            bold:True
            font_size:"8sp"
            on_release:app.root.switch_to_pageCadastro()
            background_color:[1,1,1,0]


<PageCadastro>:
    name: 'pageCadastro'
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            size_hint:.2,.06
            pos_hint:{'left':1, 'center_y':.03}
            on_release: app.root.switch_to_paginaInicial()
            background_color:(235,36,31,0)
            text: 'Voltar'
        Button:
            size_hint:.2,.06
            pos_hint:{'right':1,'center_y':.03}
            on_release: app.root.switch_to_paginaInicial()
            background_color:(235,36,31,0)
            text: 'Avançar'


<PageEsqsenha>:
    name: 'pageEsqsenha'
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            size_hint:.2,.06
            pos_hint:{'left':1, 'center_y':.03}
            on_release: app.root.switch_to_paginaInicial()
            background_color:(235,36,31,0)
            text: 'Voltar'
```

Comment: Você esqueceu de colocar na pergunta qual o erro que o programa está apresentando. Por favor edite e acrescente a mensagem completa de erro, com traceback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema está na forma que você está inserindo o nome no banco:

```
nome = self.root.ids.usuario.textinput
...
nome.execute('INSERT nome FROM cadastro')
results = cadastro.execute(nome).fetchall()
print(results)
return results
```

Totalmente sem sentido, não tem nada a ver com a forma de uso da biblioteca, fica até difícil entender o que você queria fazer!

Tente ler a documentação do `sqlalchemy` primeiro, antes de tentar usá-lo! Imagino que você queria algo assim:

```
with engine.begin() as c: 
    r = c.execute(cadastro.insert().values(nome=nome, senha=senha))
return r
```

Isso assume que o campo da sua tabela que você quer armazenar o nome chama-se `nome` - não dá pra saber no código a estrutura da sua tabela, pois ela está sendo carregada direto do banco com `autoload=True`. Você teria que passar ali também os demais campos desta tabela, no exemplo coloquei o campo `senha`.

Comment: obrigado, esta luz que eu estava precisando

Comment: @Couzer se a minha resposta atendeu, por favor, considere marcá-la como aceita para fechar a pergunta